# C++ header file includes organization

Tags: c++, header-files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ Header order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614302/c-header-order)

My question is about includes in .h files. Is it preferable to include first all the standard headers like *iostream* and only after that all users header files, or vice versa? I have googled for some time, but have not found any recommendations.

Comment: In my practice i first include the system headers and after that i include the user headers.

Comment: read also this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614302/c-header-order

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its a personal choice, I use it in following order:

```
<standard headers>
<platform headers>
<project headers>
```

Answer (score 2):

My personal preference is to go from the bottom up. So platform-specific header files go first, C++ standard header files would go next, then core libraries (like boost), then higher-level libraries (like databases), then project-specific includes.

Comment: Well, the point is that I have also read the same info in Herbert Schildt book, but my boss said me yesterday that it is a "bad coding style"... Anyway thank you for the attention.

Answer (score 0):

A `*.cc` file should first `#include` system headers, then user's headers (otherwise name clashes between system libraries and your own code will have strange behavior; but you should avoid such clashes). But you could put all the `#include`  in your header file.

You may decide to have a single user header containing all the `#include` for system headers needed by your application; this facilitates, when compiling with GCC on Linux, pre-compiled headers. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9592104/841108).

Answer (score 0):

There is already a topic about this:

[C++ Header order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614302/c-header-order)

But in general you have to ensure that there is no importance in the order of the headers.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the **include** doesn't matter, you can start with whatever you want and end also.

I don't know if i answered correctly, that's what i understood...